Scene with a "crazy" man and a watch
There was a movie where the hero or the bad guy of the movie is in a clinic (psychiatric maybe) and walks past a crazy man's room who screams and the nurse tells him that he screams as he doesn't know what time it is (it was an experiment I think).
Then we see the crazy man very calm with a watch in his hand and the hero (or bad guy?) covering his arm (as he gave the crazy man the watch)... And the nurses are wondering what happened.
What is this movie?
It's most likely from the late-90s, 2000s (pre-2010s), possibly also a TV episode. The "crazy" person was being treated as "untreatable", but all he wanted to know was the time, and the main character gave him a watch and he was super calm and really happy but all the doctors/nurses were baffled and confused. It's a short scene but darkly comical.

Welcome to Movies & TV! When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

I think you mean the 'time deprivation' experiment in IQ (1994).

Albert Einstein helps a young man [Ed] who's in love with Einstein's niece to catch her attention by pretending temporarily to be a great physicist.

Ed (Tim Robbins) and Albert Einstein (Walter Matthau) visit the lab of Dr. Moreland (Stephen Fry), where a man locked in a chamber is going insane. The man suddenly calms down when they leave, and Einstein asks where Ed's watch is. Ed replies "Since time doesn't exist, who needs a watch?" and we discover that he gave it to the man in the chamber. Here's the scene:




I think this is a scene from the movie "Patch Adams" with Robin Williams. I believe this is at the beginning where he commits himself to an asylum and he learns that he can help people sometimes by simply listening to them as opposed to having to dope them up with medication.
This becomes his philosophy for his entire medical career. Here is one of the synopsis examples from IMDB:

In 1969, Hunter Adams was a troubled man who voluntarily committed himself into a mental institution. Once there, he finds that helping his fellow inmates there gives him a purpose in life. Thus inspired, he leaves the asylum and vows to become a doctor to help people professionally. However, what he finds at medical school is a sickeningly callous philosophy that advocates an arms-length attitude to the patients that does not address their emotional needs or the quality of their lives. "Patch" Adams is determined to find a better way to help them, although the consequences of his defiance of the rules and the authorities are severe.


@Napoleon Wilson : Thanks Napoleon, I'm still not great at composing my answers in the standard formats. I appreciate the assistance :)

No problem. The help center has a good introduction to it.
